# Noob - Automating VBA cut and paste, loops?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to format a large report and would like to use macros.  For example, I may need to insert a new column every other column, then shade it and insert some data.  For the inserting new columns part, instead of:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .....repeated 1000 times  :-(
End Sub
```

I'd like to have something more like:

```
' Do this for columns A - ZZ
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns(move over 2 columns).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
'Run until Columns(":") > "ZZ:ZZ"
End Sub
```

I'm familiar with OOP in other languages, hoping someone can shed some light on looping these menial tasks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim rng As Range, x As Long

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J1")
For x = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    rng(x).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next x
```

Comment: So 
> Dim is declaring the variables rng and x, rng as a Range of values and x as a num/integer/float
> rng is assigned the value range a1 to j1

Comment: I'm not assigning the value of the Range to `rng`, but the Range itself: whenever `Set` is used in VBA then it's an object which is being assigned. This `arr = Range("A1:J1")` - or more explicitly `arr = Range("A1:J1").Value` - would assign the *values* in that range (and `arr` would then be a 2-d array)

Comment: So 

1. Dim is declaring the variables rng and x, rng as a Range of values and x as a num/integer/float  

2. rng is assigned the value range a1 to j1

3. A (recursive?) for loop begins thru the range x, incrementing by one but then stepping back (up) ??  

4. execute the formatting on the selected cell, then increment thru the next count of x?

Comment: sorry, got up and walked away mid question, this is the entireity of my comment

Comment: There's no recursion: the loop just counts backwards from (in this case) 10 to 1.